# how to correct columns and rows that nicely displays datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am working on some view in wpf mvvm. I don't know how to fix columns and rows to show correctly my datagrid. I want to have one textbox under name, one textbox under value[image]
Here is a image and xaml code, can anybody help me?

```
        <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding EnviromentVariables}" IsReadOnly="False" Margin="10" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="name" Width="*" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="value" Width="*" Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}" />
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">

                            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="{Binding ElementName =name}" />
                            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Width="{Binding ElementName= value}"/>

                            <Button Content="+" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" />
                            <Button Content="-" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
```

Comment: You have to understand layout in wpf better (tutorials about grid, stackpanel, etc.). `Grid.Row` for element inside `StackPanel` do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try first of all removing the `StackPanel`, because, even if you use `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` properties nothing will effect:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding EnviromentVariables}" IsReadOnly="False" Margin="10" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="name" Width="*" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="value" Width="*" Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Width="{Binding ElementName =name}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Width="{Binding ElementName= value}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>

        <Button Content="+" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" />
        <Button Content="-" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" />
</Grid>
```

Remember to adjust margin of Textboxes.

Comment: Great! You are wellcome.